# Search array element with certain probability weather its odd or even c++ code or algorithm

Tags: random

Give a randomized algorithm for the following scenario;
 
You want to search an element in a size of array N. The strategy you want to employ is as following; Generate a random number in the range (1,N), if the number is odd, search at that location with probability 1/3, otherwise search at probability  2/3. Make N/2 attempts, if the number is not found return -1.

I wrote this code but i am pretty much sure that its wrong i didn't give a random number

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
int i;
int numb;
int p;
cout<<"Enter a size of array"<<endl;
cin>>i;
int Search_Array[i];
for(int j=0; j<i;j++)
{
   Search_Array[j]=j;
}
cout<<"enter a number to search"<<endl;
cin>>numb;
if(numb%2==0)
   {
       p=i*(0.6);
       cout<<"value of p"<<endl<<p<<endl;
   }
   else
   {
       p=i*(0.3);
   }
while(p>0)
 {

   if(Search_Array[p]==numb)
   {
       cout<<endl<<"Search number found at location"<<endl<<p<<endl;
   }
   p--;
   cout<<endl<<p;
   }

return 0;
}
```

i have no idea how to search it with some probability help will be appreciated

Comment: I don't see any calls to the random number generator, so there's definitely something missing. Perhaps have a look at the [manpage for random](https://linux.die.net/man/3/random).

Comment: as i mentioned i didn't used any random numbers i just want to know how can i add probability to numbers in array then i will be able to search it with that certain probability

Comment: See the link i gave before, it points to https://linux.die.net/man/3/random . Just don't forget to initialize the random number generator before you use it.

Comment: can you give me some piece of code? is it possible? that would be extraordinary

Comment: float r;
  srandom(time(NULL));
    for (int i=0;i<10;i++) {
      r = (float) random() / RAND_MAX;
      printf("%f\n", r);
    } will print 10 random numbers between 0 and 1

Comment: i know how to generate random numbers but i want to putt it in array then search a random number from that array if that number is odd then search the location having the probability of 2/3 else search at probability of 1/3 thanks for quick replies

Comment: Just for clarification: I can provide support, but I will not solve your homework. To be honest, already the description of the algorithm is unclear - so far I interpreted "search at that location with probability 1/3" as, "generate a number N, generate a probability p, if p<1/3, check Search_Array[N]". The 2/3 case does not specify what happens at all. I assume that in that case you generate a new number N and check again, but you should have a second look at your problem description to clarify what is supposed to happen.

Comment: thanks that help a lot i take out my answer of it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks lambda-xy-x your answer was great and this part help a lot 
generate a probability p, if p<1/3, check Search_Array[N]"
this give me the idea how to distribute the probability thanks again